# Detect Double tap in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone

How can I detect double tap in UIScrollview?

I tried:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{ 
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (touch.tapCount == 2) {
        // some operations here
    }
}
```

But this is not detecting double tap in UIScrollView, is there any other way to detect double tap?

Regards

Comment: just be a bit more careful with formatting when posting. If you copy and paste code into your question and highlight it all and click the 011010 button above the input box it will format it properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below code for double tap.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    // other necessary operations
    UITapGestureRecognizer* dTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget : self  action : @selector (doubleTap:)];

    [doubleTap setDelaysTouchesBegan : YES];
    dTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    dTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer : dTap];
    [dTap release];
}

- (void) doubleTap : (UIGestureRecognizer*) sender
{
    NSLog (@"Double tap Do operations here...");
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was done by mistake. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 17):

If you're targeting 3.2+ you could try using a `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:yourViewController action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];
```

Then you handle the tap in your viewcontroller:

```
- (void)tapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSUInteger numTaps = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];
    if (numTaps== 2) {
         //some operations here
    }
}
```

Use this Code

Comment: Thanks Gyani for replying, but scrollview is not detecting any touch event....is there other way to detect double tab in scrollview?

Comment: u may get some help from http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/detect-single-tap-in-uiscrollview.html