# Scroll View Images Description

Tags: xcode, image, scrollview

I have a ScrollViewer containing a gallery of images and need to add the function of "pop up" with the description of each image, ie when the function will receive the ScrollViewer singletap displays information about this specific picture, anyone have any idea how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Hey! If my answer was helpful, please accept it. Otherwise, please provide further information.

Answer (score 1):

I would put a `UILabel` (properbly with black, semi transparent background and white Text) above the `UIScrollView`. When it is taped (see how you detect taps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905125/detect-double-tap-in-uiscrollview)) you could fill the `UILabel` with the current image's description and make it visible or fade it in. Once the scrollview stars scrolling again (use `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` from the `UIScrollViews` delegate) you can hide the Label again.